# Bundle is nullable even though I haven't declared it as such

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable

```
class UserFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

private val userBinding: FragmentUserBinding by onCreateView<Fragment, FragmentUserBinding>(R.layout.fragment_user)
val user: ObservableField<String> = ObservableField()
private var bundle = Bundle()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    userBinding.main = this
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = userBinding.root!!

override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
    runAnimation(500L, Techniques.RubberBand, p0)
    Handler().postDelayed({
        saveUserAndStartLetterFragment()
    }, 700L)
}

private fun saveUserAndStartLetterFragment() {
    var fragment = WordpackChooserFragment()
    bundle.putString("User",user.get())
    fragment.arguments = bundle
    activity!!.supportFragmentManager.replaceFragment(fragment, activity!!.findViewById(R.id.flContainer))
}
}
```

In this fragment I declare the bundle. I do not specify it as nullable.

```
class WordpackChooserFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

private val wordpackChooserBinding: FragmentWordpackChooserBinding by onCreateView<Fragment, FragmentWordpackChooserBinding>(R.layout.fragment_wordpack_chooser)
private var bundle: Bundle = Bundle()
private lateinit var fragment: Fragment

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    wordpackChooserBinding.main = this
    setRecycler()
    bundle = arguments
    return wordpackChooserBinding.root
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    fragment = RoundsChooserFragment()
    bundle.putStringArrayList("Wordpack", selectedPack)
    fragment.arguments = bundle
    activity!!.supportFragmentManager.replaceFragment(fragment, activity!!.findViewById(R.id.flContainer))
}

private fun setRecycler() {
    wordpackChooserBinding.root.btn_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    wordpackChooserBinding.root.btn_recycler.adapter = BtnAdapter(this)
    wordpackChooserBinding.root.btn_recycler.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

}
```

In this fragment this line `bundle = arguments` errors with the following:

Type mismatch.

Required: Bundle

Found: Bundle?

I can use the non-null assertion operator '!!' but It seems like a hack.

Comment: That's cuz `getArguments()` is marked `@Nullable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arguments` is [nullable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()) (note the "if any" in the description of the link), therefore you can not simply assign it to a non-nullable `Bundle`. You would either handle the case of it being `null` (using an if), using `!!` or you could write something like this:

```
arguments?.let { bundle = it }
```

However, I'd say its preferred to use `let`.

Comment: You're welcome! There is also a great [article](https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84) about Kotlin standard functions. Definitely worth checking out!